# Implement google/facebbok login for an android app

Tags: android

what is the simplest way to implement google/facebook login for an android app?

I'm bamboozled by all the different ways. Some online examples look outdated, and some I'm not clear when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinion questions, so I will give you mine.  The easiest way is to use the SDK's provided by Facebook and Google directly and follow their online tutorials.  I have tried many different solutions, and find that at the end of the day, the cleanest and most extendible approach is to implement the vendor-provided SDKs directly (it also makes upgrading easier, and makes you less dependent on 3rd party restrictions).

Google integration guide:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Facebook integration guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Did you use google sign-in or google identity toolkit? - can you provide any links please? thanks